# Diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial splits into pairwise distinct linear factors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, minimal-polynomials

I have the following well known theorem:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$, $\dim_KV=n$ and let $\phi:V\to V$ be an endomorphism. It is $\phi$ diagonalizable iff $\text{minpoly}_\phi(t)=\prod_{i=1}^m (t-\lambda_i)$ with $\lambda_i\not=\lambda_j$ for $i\not=j$.

I know this question could be a duplicate, but I have a concrete question about my try to prove this $"\Rightarrow "$ direction.

My try: $\phi$ is diagonalizable, therefore the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$ splits into linear factors: $\chi_{\phi}(t)=\prod_{i=1}^m (t-\lambda_i)^{k_i}$ with $\lambda_i\not=\lambda_j$ for $i\not=j$ and $k_i\ge 1$ and the geometric multiplicity of the $\lambda_i's$ is the same as the algebraic multiplicity. Because of $\phi$ is diagonalizable, there exists a basis of $V$,$(v_1,...,v_n),$ of eigenvectors of $\phi$ related to the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial, therefore it is $\text{minpoly}_\phi(t)=\prod_{i=1}^m (t-\lambda_i)^{t_i}$ with $t_i\le k_i$ for every i. Let $g(t)=\prod_{i=1}^m (t-\lambda_i)$. Claim: $g=\text{minpoly}_\phi$.

First of all $g$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$, therefore I have to show that $g(\phi)=0$, this means $g(\phi)(v)=0$ for every $v\in V$.

Let $v\in V, v=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_kv_k$. It is $\def\id{\mathrm{id}}g(\phi)(v)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_kg(\phi)(v_k)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (\phi-\lambda_i\id)(v_k)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (\phi(v_k)-\lambda_i\id(v_k))=0$, because for an $i\in\{1,..,m\}$ it is $i=k$. This shows $\Rightarrow$ (i hope).

My question is: Is the equation $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (\phi-\lambda_i\id)(v_k)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (\phi(v_k)-\lambda_i\id(v_k))$ true? I think yes, but I'm not sure.

Could you give me a proof or explain me, how to construct a basis of eigenvectors of this $\Leftarrow$ direction? Regards.

Edit: Is there a mistake in the formulation of the theorem (see comments below)?I have found a proof for the direction $\Leftarrow$: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/minimal.pdf

Comment: The identity matrix is a counterexample to this theorem.

Comment: hm, no? the identity matrix is diagonalizable and $\text{minpoly}_{id}(t)=(t-1)$? I don't see the mistake.. Maybe I have a mistake in the formulation

Comment: Please don't type `<br/>` all the time, just leave a blank line to start a new paragraph. This is much more readable.

Comment: sorry! I will do/change this in feature.

Comment: I don't get the RHS of your equation. How do you multiply a bunch of vectors?

Comment: ok, I see this equation is wrong=(. But I have no idea how to repare the $\Rightarrow$-direction

Comment: Curious, you are asking about the **easy** direction of this result, which is also the case (for the same problem) in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225675/) asked only yesterday. You are doing a lot of unnecessary stuff. All that you need is that minimal polynomials of similar matrices are equal, so that you can reduce to the case of a _diagonal_ matrix; and to observe that for a diagonal matrix $D$ with diagonal entries $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ and any polynomial $P$ one has that $P[D]$ is diagonal with diagonal entries$P[d_1],\ldots,P[d_n]$. The minimal poly should now be obvious.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen: thank you. this is what cames first into my mind. But I dont see, why the minimal polynomial has simple zeros, what is if there are $i\not= j$, but $d_i=d_j$?

Comment: Did you read [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1225706/18880) at the linked question? It is quite explicit about this: if there are _multiple equal_ diagonal entries with value $d$, only one factor $X-d$ goes into the product that forms the minimal polynomial. Which therefore is by construction a product of _distinct_ monic factors of degree$~1$. In fact you are doing the same thing in your attempt.

Comment: sorry, I read this but it needed a longer time to understand it, sorry, now it's clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

$\def\id{\mathrm{id}}$The equation $$
  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (\phi-\lambda_i\id)(v_k)
 =\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (\phi(v_k)-\lambda_i\id(v_k))$$
that you are asking about is nonsensical, so it is neither true not false. The left hand side should be written
$$
  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\left(\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (\phi-\lambda_i\id)\right)(v_k)\right)
$$
to express what it means: a product (composition) of polynomials in $\phi$, applied to $v_k$, then multiplied by the scalar $\mu_k$ and summed. [The inner large parentheses are obligatory, since function application binds more strongly than the large operator $\prod$ does (to the right); the outer parentheses are just for readability, since function application also binds more strongly than multiplication.] Your error is maybe misreading your own formula, thinking that the function application is taking place in each factor of the product (which is in fact a function composition), essentially interpreting $(\phi_1\circ\cdots\circ \phi_m)(v_k)$ as a "product of vectors" $\phi_1(v_k)\phi_2(v_k)\ldots\phi_m(v_k)$ that makes no sense.

Instead you can argue that the expression is$~0$ because the polynomials in$~\phi$ commute, so that you can move the factor $\phi-\lambda_i\id$ for which $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue of $v_k$ to the right, so that it acts on $v_k$ first; the result is the zero vector, and then the other factors will leave it zero because they are *linear* operators.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you mean I yould write $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\prod\limits_{ i=1}^m (\phi-\lambda_i\id)(v_k)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\prod\limits_{ i=1\; i\not= k }^m (\phi-\lambda_i\id)(\phi-\lambda_k\id)(v_k)=                \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\mu_k\prod\limits_{ i=1\; i\not= k }^m (\phi-\lambda_i\id)(\phi(v_k)-\lambda_k\id (v_k))=0$

Comment: I'm sorry.. I have problems with LaTeX and formel editor's in general, it is new for me.. I try my best to learn

Comment: Yes, I think that is exactly what I meant. Don't worry too much about LaTeX in comments, it's horrible, and occasionally the system will actually break correct LaTeX by inserting a space (invisible to you) in a random place because it thinks that this is getting too long for a line (which bug you can circumvent by placing some spaces yourself in harmless places). By the way, you can type `\neq` instead of `\not=`.

Comment: ok thank's. everything is clear now. I really need a break now from this question.. Later I will vote up your answers. I really appreciate your help, thank you! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record for this old question, and even though it does not touch on the actual question (which I dealt with in my other answer), I must note that you are asking about the *easy* direction of the equivalence, and the whole passage by the characteristic polynomial and the Cayley-Hamilton theorem is not needed at all. Here are two arguments why a diagonalisable endomorphism$~\phi$ has a split minimal polynomial with simple roots.

Let $\Lambda$ be the spectrum of$~\phi$, the set of eigenvalues without (as it befits a set) multiplicity. We show $P[\phi]=0$ if and only $P[\lambda]=0$ for every $\lambda\in\Lambda$, so that $\mu_\phi=\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda}(X-\lambda)$ is clearly the minimal polynomial, and it is split with simple roots.

First without coordinates: for any eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda\in\Lambda$ and any polynomial $P$ one has $P[\phi](v)=P[\lambda]v$ (using $\phi^k(v)=\lambda^kv$ and linearity), so $P[\phi](v)=0$ if and only if $\lambda$ is a root of $P$. In order for $P[\phi]$ to be $0$ it is necessary that this happens for all $\lambda\in\Lambda$, but this is also sufficient since every vector$~w$ can be written as a sum of eigenvectors, and by linearity if $P[\phi]$ kills those eigenvectors, it kills $w$ as well.

In coordinates it is also evident: since $\phi$ is diagonalisable we can represent it on some basis by a diagonal matrix $\def\diag{\operatorname{diag}}\diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ for which $\{ \lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}=\Lambda$. Now for any polynomial $P$, the matrix of $P[\phi]$ is $P[D]=\diag(P[\lambda_1],\ldots,P[\lambda_n])$, and this is zero if and only if every $\lambda\in\Lambda$ is root of $P$.